# Best approach to create a troubleshouting section?

Tags: 7, forms, nodes

I am looking to create some kind of troubleshooting section on a website. Sort of like the Windows help with some sections, questions and answers.

I was thinking of doing this with a regular Book, and write a small form module which allows me to track the page with a "Was this information helpful or not?" question.

But are there possible alternatives, either existing modules or an approach which works best?

Answer (score 1):

If you go down the book route then you can always use the [flag](http://drupal.org/project/flag) module for the "Was this information helpful".

There is also the [FAQ](http://drupal.org/project/faq) module which doesn't quite fit your use case but might be worth checking out just in case.